# Is there a way to login into twitter with auth token

Tags: authentication, twitter

is there a way to login into twitter with auth token I have tried to use EditThisCookie extension to change the auth_token value in the cookies with my token to log into twitter without asking for my email and password but it didn't seem to work there is a video to show what Iam trying to do https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q6ZG1blxug&ab_channel=WebMasterMarket

Comment: Probably not, auth tokens are usually meant to be consumed by APIs, not by humans or to be used as a session cookie.

Comment: Is there any other way to login with the token or the cookies.